# Assigning IP block to CentOS with different netmask & gateway

Tags: linux, networking, configuration, centos

Trying to assign an IP block in CentOS 6.4:

> IP Range: 23.252.117.2 to 23.252.117.14
>
> Netmask: 255.255.255.240
>
> Gateway: 23.252.117.1

I've tried doing it through ifcfg-eth0-range0:

> IPADDR_START=23.252.117.2
>
> IPADDR_END=23.252.117.14
>
> CLONENUM_START=10
>
> NETMASK=255.255.255.240
>
> BROADCAST=23.252.117.15
>
> GATEWAY=23.252.117.1

When I use

> ifup ifcfg-eth0-range0

It returns

> Device does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.

Network restart appears to assign the IPs however they do not work properly (I use them for Minecraft servers and they can't be connected to through IPs in ifcfg-eth0-range0)

Any ideas?